# How to add/modify LDAP entry using PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

So I have the following code to retrieve an LDAP record

```
$filter = "(&(givenName=myfirstname)(sn=mylastname)";
$ldapconnectionid = @ldap_connect("my-host-here");
$ldapbindid = @ldap_bind($ldapconnectionid, "my-bind-dn", "my-password");
$ldapsearch = @ldap_search($ldapconnectionid, $basedn, $filter));
$ldapgetentries = @ldap_get_entries($ldapconnectionid, $ldapsearch));

echo "<pre>";print_r($ldapgetentries);echo "</pre>";
var_dump($ldapgetentries);
```

And the results are displayed at the bottom.

I tried this 2 commands

```
$ldapadd = @ldap_add($ldapconnectionid, "my-dn", array( "personRole" => array( "count" => 1, 0 => "ProspectiveClient")));
$ldapmodify = @ldap_modify($ldapconnectionid, "my-dn", array( "personDOB" => array( "count" => 1, 0 => "1990-01-01")));
```

And both returned false (i.e. the operation is unsuccessful). I've checked with the person in charge of our LDAP server and she said the account I'm using to bind definitely has write access.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I have a feeling the array value I'm passing to the LDAP functions are wrong.

Thanks a lot!

ps. I've replaced host, username, password and etc with fake ones since I cannot share corporate info.

**results of var_dump**

```
array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> array(44) { ["formusermove"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(4) "true" } [0]=> string(12) "formusermove" ["pwdset"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(5) "false" } [1]=> string(6) "pwdset" ["ATTpersondirectoryid"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(6) "370356" } [2]=> string(25) "ATTpersondirectoryid" ["ATTpersondob"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(10) "1990-01-01" } [3]=> string(17) "ATTpersondob" ["ATTpersonclientnumber"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(7) "1234567" } [4]=> string(27) "ATTpersonclientnumber" ["dirxml-passwordsyncstatus"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(100) "CFDD2797F6FCCF4DE3A9CFDD2797F6FC20160715032057530000000000001Code(-8032) Operation vetoed by policy." } [5]=> string(25) "dirxml-passwordsyncstatus" ["dirxml-associations"]=> array(3) { ["count"]=> int(2) [0]=> string(56) "cn=UAT-GEN-LOOPBACK,cn=Driver Set,o=RESOURCES#1#myusername" [1]=> string(53) "cn=UAT-SA-TEXT-IN,cn=Driver Set,o=RESOURCES#1#1234567" } [6]=> string(19) "dirxml-associations" ["uid"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(8) "myusername" } [7]=> string(3) "uid" ["givenname"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(4) "John" } [8]=> string(9) "givenname" ["fullname"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(10) "John Smith" } [9]=> string(8) "fullname" ["title"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(2) "Ms" } [10]=> string(5) "title" ["sn"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(5) "Smith" } [11]=> string(2) "sn" ["passworduniquerequired"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(5) "FALSE" } [12]=> string(22) "passworduniquerequired" ["passwordrequired"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(4) "TRUE" } [13]=> string(16) "passwordrequired" ["passwordminimumlength"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(1) "6" } [14]=> string(21) "passwordminimumlength" ["passwordallowchange"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(4) "TRUE" } [15]=> string(19) "passwordallowchange" ["objectclass"]=> array(9) { ["count"]=> int(8) [0]=> string(13) "inetOrgPerson" [1]=> string(13) "srvprvUserAux" [2]=> string(14) "ATTPerson" [3]=> string(20) "organizationalPerson" [4]=> string(6) "Person" [5]=> string(18) "ndsLoginProperties" [6]=> string(3) "Top" [7]=> string(29) "DirXML-PasswordSyncStatusUser" } [16]=> string(11) "objectclass" ["loginexpirationtime"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(15) "20161231000000Z" } [17]=> string(19) "loginexpirationtime" ["logindisabled"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(4) "TRUE" } [18]=> string(13) "logindisabled" ["cn"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(8) "myusername" } [19]=> string(2) "cn" ["acl"]=> array(7) { ["count"]=> int(6) [0]=> string(74) "2#subtree#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#[All Attributes Rights]" [1]=> string(60) "6#entry#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#loginScript" [2]=> string(30) "2#entry#[Public]#messageServer" [3]=> string(30) "2#entry#[Root]#groupMembership" [4]=> string(70) "6#entry#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#printJobConfiguration" [5]=> string(29) "2#entry#[Root]#networkAddress" } [20]=> string(3) "acl" ["count"]=> int(21) ["dn"]=> string(40) "cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA" } }
```

**results of print_r**

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [formusermove] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => true
                )

            [0] => formusermove
            [pwdset] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => false
                )

            [1] => pwdset
            [ATTpersondirectoryid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 370356
                )

            [2] => ATTpersondirectoryid
            [ATTpersondob] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 1990-01-01
                )

            [3] => ATTpersondob
            [ATTpersonclientnumber] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 1234567
                )

            [4] => ATTpersonclientnumber
            [dirxml-passwordsyncstatus] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CFDD2797F6FCCF4DE3A9CFDD2797F6FC20160715032057530000000000001Code(-8032) Operation vetoed by policy.
                )

            [5] => dirxml-passwordsyncstatus
            [dirxml-associations] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [0] => cn=UAT-GEN-LOOPBACK,cn=Driver Set,o=RESOURCES#1#myusername
                    [1] => cn=UAT-SA-TEXT-IN,cn=Driver Set,o=RESOURCES#1#1234567
                )

            [6] => dirxml-associations
            [uid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => myusername
                )

            [7] => uid
            [givenname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => John
                )

            [8] => givenname
            [fullname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => John Smith
                )

            [9] => fullname
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Ms
                )

            [10] => title
            [sn] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Smith
                )

            [11] => sn
            [passworduniquerequired] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => FALSE
                )

            [12] => passworduniquerequired
            [passwordrequired] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => TRUE
                )

            [13] => passwordrequired
            [passwordminimumlength] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 6
                )

            [14] => passwordminimumlength
            [passwordallowchange] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => TRUE
                )

            [15] => passwordallowchange
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 8
                    [0] => inetOrgPerson
                    [1] => srvprvUserAux
                    [2] => ATTPerson
                    [3] => organizationalPerson
                    [4] => Person
                    [5] => ndsLoginProperties
                    [6] => Top
                    [7] => DirXML-PasswordSyncStatusUser
                )

            [16] => objectclass
            [loginexpirationtime] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 20161231000000Z
                )

            [17] => loginexpirationtime
            [logindisabled] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => TRUE
                )

            [18] => logindisabled
            [cn] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => myusername
                )

            [19] => cn
            [acl] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 6
                    [0] => 2#subtree#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#[All Attributes Rights]
                    [1] => 6#entry#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#loginScript
                    [2] => 2#entry#[Public]#messageServer
                    [3] => 2#entry#[Root]#groupMembership
                    [4] => 6#entry#cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA#printJobConfiguration
                    [5] => 2#entry#[Root]#networkAddress
                )

            [20] => acl
            [count] => 21
            [dn] => cn=myusername,ou=INACTIVE,ou=PEOPLE,o=DATA
        )

)
```

Comment: Maybe a piece of code is missing, but are all keys of `$parameters` correctly set? Could you `var_dump($parameters)`?

Comment: $parameters contain corporate hosts and info which I cannot share but be assured that I can successfully connect and query our LDAP server using whatever values are stored in there

Comment: Have you had a look a t the documentation at https://php.net/ldap_add ? And did you check what error acctually occurs vial ldap_error?